# Javapos Set Department of TH230

Tags: printing, javapos

i have not used javapos before. Now i must set/get the department of one Th230 FiscalPrinter. I have found that i must use directIO, but the documentation is very limited.
Can you advice how to do this? Is there any documentation of the methods or Fiscalprinter class in javapos?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the complete documentation here: http://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?retail/2017-07-32

JavaPOS is now part of "UnifiedPOS".

The document is entitled "UnifiedPOS. Retail Peripheral Architecture"

Answer (score 0):

Since the DirectIO method is specialized to a specific vendor and specific equipment, detailed information is only available to the vendor who provides it.
Please ask the vendor or retailer offering that printer.